# Oracle - SQL Code

Tags: sql, oracle, procedure

I am trying to write a Procedure that updates a field on a table.  I am new to Oracle but think I got a good start.

Here is my code:

```
create or replace procedure UPDATETSTFLAG(iflag varchar2)

IS 
uflag varchar2(1);
     BEGIN  
      SELECT INITIAL_FLAG
        INTO uflag 
      FROM chcohm.chs_skin_test
       WHERE INITIAL_FLAG = 'I';
         IF uflag = ' ' 
            THEN update Initial_Flag = 'C'
         END IF;
     END;
```

I am getting errors and not sure where to go from here.

Comment: what are the errors?

Comment: At least missng ; after UPDATE command and wrong syntax. UPDATE table_name SET field_name1 = value1 WHERE field_name2 = value2. And what is IFLAG parameter if you dont' use it at all?

Comment: read this:  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/nav/portal_5.htm#sql_and_pl_sql   more specifically:  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10008.htm#SQLRF01708

Comment: *I am getting errors* is not a meaningful problem description. You know **exactly** what errors you're getting, because they're on the screen right in front of you. It's ridiculous that you couldn't be bothered to include them in your question. You're asking us to donate **our** time to solve **your** problem for free; the very least you could do is provide the details that are **right in front of you** that would make it easier for us to help.

Comment: Given you are selecting "WHERE INITIAL_FLAG = 'I'", how on earth could it ever come back with any INITIAL_FLAG value besides 'I' ?

Comment: "You know exactly what errors you're getting, because they're on the screen right in front of you." Unless OP is using SQL*Plus, which requires typing `show errors` to get the errors from stored procedure creation. @Nette, if that is the case, please type `show errors` and include the detailed error message in your question.

Answer (score 1):

As a start.... but I also question whether UFLAG will ever equal ' '.  That implies the application is updating the table with an empty string.  '' and NULL are the same in Oracle but ' ' is even more problematic.  Perhaps you mean IF UFLAG IS NULL THEN  ?

As others have pointed out you never use the IFLAG parameter and this procedure will also fail if there is more than one record in the CHS_SKIN_TEST table.  You need to add a primary key filter to the statements.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE UPDATETSTFLAG(IFLAG IN VARCHAR2)

 IS
  UFLAG VARCHAR2(1);
BEGIN
  SELECT INITIAL_FLAG
    INTO UFLAG
    FROM CHCOHM.CHS_SKIN_TEST
   WHERE INITIAL_FLAG = 'I';
  IF UFLAG = ' ' THEN
    UPDATE CHCOHM.CHS_SKIN_TEST
       SET INITIAL_FLAG = 'C'
     WHERE ** NEED TO HAVE A PRIMARY KEY HERE * = ** THE RECORD YOU NEED TO
     UPDATE **;
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Well, it would help to give a little more insight on the process.  I have a able that never updates the Intial_Flag even though the data is imported.  So, all I am trying to do is update the Initial_Flag on the table from 'I' to 'C'.  I just have a feeling that I am not on the right page.

Comment: @Nette from what you say this could all be done as a single sql statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace procedure UPDATETSTFLAG(iflag varchar2)
IS 
BEGIN
  uflag varchar2(1)

  -- The value of @uflag will always be; 'I' or NULL
  SELECT @uflag = Initial_Flag  
  FROM chcohm.chs_skin_test 
  WHERE INITIAL_FLAG = 'I'

  -- This will never evaluate to TURE. See comment above.
  IF @uflag = ' ' THEN 
    UPDATE chcohm.chs_skin_test 
    SET Initial_Flag = 'C'  
    WHERE INITIAL_FLAG = 'I'
  END IF
END;
```